# How can I check if the device, which is using my website, is a mobile user or not

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to check if the device which is using my website is on a mobile or any other device. It's a quick question with a quick answer I hope.

Comment: Exactly why do you want this - there may be other ways to get the required result than "mobile or not"

Comment: You can check the width of the viewport with `window.innerWidth`. If you need to check the actual browser used, please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: Generally, testing veiwport width is preferable to testing for actual "mobile"-ness. If someone's on a mobile device w/ full resolution, why not just show them the desktop UI (and the converse, if they have a tiny screen on desktop why not use the mobile UI?) Might be worth adding some more details here. There are other things you can test for specific UX concerns, like testing whether the browser has a mouse or is touchscreen-only.

Comment: there is a library called is-mobile https://github.com/juliangruber/is-mobile, it could be useful for your case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to see if the user's device is mobile, the MDN docs advises to look for the property `maxTouchPoints` in the **navigator** (or browser) object and see if the value is `> 0`.

In the past this used to be done with *User Agent Sniffing* ([Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)), i.e going through the user-agent header sent by the browser into the `navigator.userAgent` property to see if it contains certain keywords. This method however has limitations and may not always tell the right kind of device the user is on because many devices today support different browsers and features and vice versa.

#### Using User Agent Sniffing (Not recommended today, should be used only as a fallback)

```
var hasTouchScreen = false;

var UA = navigator.userAgent;
        hasTouchScreen = (
            /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(UA) ||
            /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(UA)
        ); 

if (hasTouchScreen) {
    // Device is likely mobile, so do stuff for mobile devices here.
}
```

#### Check using `maxTouchPoints` property and if `> 0` in `navigator` object (MDN Docs Recommended)

```
var hasTouchScreen = false;

if ("maxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
    hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
} 

if (hasTouchScreen) {
    // Device is likely mobile, so do stuff for mobile devices here.
}
```

Be aware, that not all browsers may support that specification, so the navigator object may not have the property `maxTouchPoints` or some mobile devices may have large screens and some desktop devices may have small touch-screens or some people may use smart TVs and so on. So a better way to do this check would be to combine the snippet above with some fallbacks:

#### Better way to detect mobile devices using a combination of previous method and fallbacks (Most Robust Method, MDN Docs Recommended)

```
var hasTouchScreen = false;

if ("maxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
    hasTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
} else if ("msMaxTouchPoints" in navigator) {
    hasTouchScreen = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
} else {
    var mQ = window.matchMedia && matchMedia("(pointer:coarse)");
    if (mQ && mQ.media === "(pointer:coarse)") {
        hasTouchScreen = !!mQ.matches;
    } else if ('orientation' in window) {
        hasTouchScreen = true; // deprecated, but good fallback
    } else {
        // Only as a last resort, fall back to user agent sniffing
        var UA = navigator.userAgent;
        hasTouchScreen = (
            /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(UA) ||
            /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(UA)
        );
    }
}

if (hasTouchScreen)
    // Do something here. 
}
```

[Read more about browser detection using the user agent and the recommended way for mobile device detection here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) (For the recommended method for mobile device detection, look under the "Mobile device detection" subheading).

Comment: This "recommended" method makes no sense for detecting if the user is actually on a mobile device. It will detect any device with a touchscreen, like a 27" touch monitor or a touchscreen laptop and that is pretty stupid.
The best way to detect mobile devices especially for the sake of making your web page responsive is checking the window.innerWidth value.

Comment: Like FightRay says, this answer doesn't make any sense.  But looking at the viewport size is only appropriate for layout.  For many cases checking the user agent string is still needed, no matter how much MDN would like to pretend otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is to check:

```
user agent + screen resolution + touch  event  + media queries
```

Here is the full code:

```
const isUserUsingMobile = () => {

// User agent string method
let isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

// Screen resolution method
if (!isMobile) {
    let screenWidth = window.screen.width;
    let screenHeight = window.screen.height;
    isMobile = (screenWidth < 768 || screenHeight < 768);
}

// Touch events method
if (!isMobile) {
    isMobile = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
}

// CSS media queries method
if (!isMobile) {
    let bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    isMobile = window.getComputedStyle(bodyElement).getPropertyValue('content').indexOf('mobile') !== -1;
}

return isMobile
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this condition in javascript:

```
if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
//do your stuff here
}
```